# Microsoft Graph List OneDrive Items

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I want to list all my OneDrive for Business Items in an UWP-Application. For this I'm using "Microsoft Graph Client Library" from NuGet. It's a wrapper Library for the Microsoft Graph REST-API.

When I'm trying to get all items or children (I tried both) from my root-drive or from an spezific Folder-ID, I just get an empty List. But there are different Files and Folders in my Drive. Even when I'm using the REST-API without this wrapper, I'm getting just an empty Result.

But when I'm using the "Recent" function, I'm getting a list of my recent used Items.

```
// Returns an empty result without error
GraphServiceClient.Me.Drive.Items.Request().GetAsync()
GraphServiceClient.Me.Drive.Root.Children.Request().GetAsync()
GraphServiceClient.Drives["id"].Items.Request().GetAsync()

// Returns all my recent used items
GraphServiceClient.Me.Drive.Recent().Request().GetAsync()
GraphServiceClient.Drives["id"].Recent().Request().GetAsync()
```

The HTTP-Traffic Looks like:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children HTTP/1.1
SdkVersion: graph-dotnet-1.0.1
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
Authorization: Bearer 1234567890123456789
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Connection: Keep-Alive

// Response:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
request-id: 123456-7890123
client-request-id: 123456-7890123
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West Europe","Slice":"SliceB","ScaleUnit":"000","Host":"AGSFE_IN_3","ADSiteName":"AMS"}}
OData-Version: 4.0
Duration: 823.6454
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 15 Jun 2016 06:56:29 GMT

8c
{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('123456-7890123-456789')/drive/root/children","value":[]}
0
```

(I've removed the Id's, so thats not the Problem)

Can someone help?

Comment: The Items collection isn't enumerable, so that would be expected to fail. You need to use Root.Children to get to items. However, it looks like that isn't work for you either. Can you use Fiddler to get a trace of the actual HTTP traffic and share the response?

Answer (score 2):

To get the items from OneDrive using the Microsoft Graph, we need to make the request to the endpoint. The ‘Request’ method didn’t make the real request until we call ‘GetAsync’ method.

Here is an example that get the children items of the default drive:

```
var items = await graphserviceClient.Me.Drive.Root.Children.Request().GetAsync();
```

Refer to [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/docs/overview.md) for more detail about this SDK.

Comment: Oh sorry. I forgot to copy the "GetAsync" Part of my request. I'm getting a result with an empty Children List.

Comment: Was the issue fixed after you adding the 'GetAsync' method?

Comment: No. I already used it. I just forgot to copy it! See the comment above.

Comment: The 'recent files' lists a set of items that have been recently used by the signed in user. This list includes items that are in the user's drive as well as items they have access to from **other drives**. To make sure that there are files on your drive, you can login the [Office 365](https://login.microsoftonline.com) and click the 'OneDrive' icon on the portal.

Comment: The files are part of my OneDrive! I've used the OneDrive for Business Webseite to upload / create them.